# Solve delay differential equations manually. Why does this return horizon line?

Tags: differential-equations

From [Sample](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDelayDifferentialEquations.html.en?source=footer),This works correctly.

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t - 1] == 0, x[t /; t <= 0] == t^2}, x, {t, -1, 5}];

Plot[sol[x], {x, -1, 5}]
```

Now I want to solve the above via Taylor expansion.

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] - x'[t] == 0, x[t /; t <= 0] == t^2}, 
  x, {t, -1, 5}]
```

This returns a horizontal line. Obviously not the correct. Why?

add)
I tried the following with reference to comments.
Although this works certainly, there is still an error.
How does NDSolve solve the above(top's) delayed equation?

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] - x'[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, 
   x'[0] == -0.1}, x, {t, 0, 5}];
Plot[sol[x],{x,0,5}]
```

Comment: You have to specify the initial conditions differently: `NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] - x'[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 2}, x, {t, 0, 5}]` works as expected.

Comment: Looking at the sample diagram(unfortunately MMA 11.0.1 can't solve the sample)  I would expect a negativ initial slope x'[0]!

Comment: @Xminer What error do you mean? On my machine (11.3.0.0), there are no error messages. But I don't get why you set `x'[0]==0.1` - to reproduce the result above, you need to set it to `x'[0]==2`.

Comment: I mean "error" is "the difference between True Answer(by NDSolve) and My Answer(via Taylor Expansion). I set $x'[0]==-0.1$ because $x'[0]=2$ doesn't reproduce the same result as`NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t - 1] == 0, x[t /; t <= 0] == t^2}, 
x, {t, -1, 5}]`